# metadata in webshop with multiple product on page

Tags: magento, metadata, product, schema.org

We have a webshop in Magento that has a lot of grouped products. A grouped product page has the basic info, and then a table with all the products in it. This table contains for each row the SKU, some attributes and the price. I want to add metadata (from [schema.org](http://schema.org)) to it, but I'm not sure how to do this.

I tried it by adding an itemtype product for each and every row in that table, but that doesn't link to the product name in any way. I have also tried to make the whole page a product, but that doesn't give the desired result.

Has anyone come across this before and has solved it? Any input is welcome!

The page I'm working on: [clickie](http://induweb.nl/verspanen/boren/cilindrische-schacht/induweb-spiraalboor-hss-rolgewalst-din-338-type-n.html)

Comment: It's hard to say w/out looking at the page. I'd propose to use *product * +*offer* for each row depending on the attributes. I didn't get issue with the name. But if you have it in other part of the page you can use *itemref*. And what is the desired result you're looking for? Anyway page example would be very helpful to answer your question.

Comment: @ajax I have added a link to the page I'm working on. It's hard because it's multiple products actually, but with minimal details since the rest of the page describes everything for that group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact in every row you have a bit different product (differs by diameter, length, etc). Ideally you should indicate this using *schema.org/Product* nested in *schema.org/Offer* and linked with general product information using *itemref*. Smth like this:

```
<div id="product_general">
    <h1 itemprop="name" >Induweb spiraalboor, HSS, Rolgewalst, DIN 338, type N</h1>
</div>

<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
    <div itemprop="itemOffered" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product" itemref="product_general">
        <span itemprop="model">Diameter: 1.0</span>
    </div>
    <span itemprop="Price">€ 0,13</span>
</div>
```

The issue here is that you're using *table* for specific product and offer information. It seems there is no way to make a construction above in your current design with valid html code. However this is not a big problem for you if you're looking more for Rich Snippets than for super correct markup.

So your issue with Rich Snippets now is that highest price is not correct. 
[image]

You can easily fight this using *schema.org/AggregateOffer*. In your current code (light version):

```
<div class="wrapper product-view" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">

    <h1 itemprop="name" id="product_name">Induweb spiraalboor, HSS, Rolgewalst, DIN 338, type N</h1>
    <img itemprop="image" src="http://induweb.nl/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/185x/5e06319eda06f020e43594a9c230972d/import/Verspanen/Boren/Cylindrische schacht/100000002-induweb-spiraalboor-hss-rolgewalst-din-338-type-n_0/induweb.nl--100000002-30.jpg" alt="Induweb spiraalboor, HSS, Rolgewalst, DIN 338, type N" title="Induweb spiraalboor, HSS, Rolgewalst, DIN 338, type N" />
    <table><tr><td itemprop="brand">InduWeb</td></tr></table>
    <div  itemprop="description">
                        <p>&middot; Rolgewalst <br />&middot; Cilinderschacht <br />&middot; Rechtssnijdend <br />&middot; Kegelmantelgeslepen 118&deg; <br />&middot; Zwarte uitvoering</p>                    </div>

    <!-- Put http://AggregateOffer here with high and low price properties-->
    <div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateOffer">
        <meta itemprop="lowPrice" content="€ 0,13">
        <meta itemprop="highPrice" content="€ 1.75">
        <meta itemprop="offerCount" content="98">
    </div>
    <!-- End of AggregateOffer-->    

    <table>
    <tr itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer" itemprop="offers">
        <td itemprop="sku">
            <div class="shipping shipping-176" itemprop="availability" content="in_stock"></div>
            100010006
        </td>

        <!-- Start sub attributen -->
        <!--  -->
        <td class="a-center">1.0</td>
        <!--  -->
        <td class="a-center">34</td>
        <!--  -->
        <td class="a-center">12</td>
        <!-- Einde sub attributen -->

        <td class="a-center" style="width: 25px;"><p>10</p></td>

        <td>
            <span itemprop="price">
                <span class="price">€ 0,13</span>
            </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Although it's not semantically super correct but it will give pretty good result:

[image]